# Difference between p values of interaction

Tags: anova, interaction, p-value

I was wondering which p-value to use when i am testing the significance of an interaction between two continuous variables.

Here is my model with the interaction:

Coefficients:

```
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       110.2584    23.9969   4.595 0.000417 ***
lg_hag              36.0716    18.2778   1.974 0.068510 .      
raceblack         -12.9419     1.8198  -7.112 5.24e-06 ***
racemexican        -9.0254     2.3207  -3.889 0.001636 ** 
racemulti/other    -9.8012     2.0640  -4.749 0.000311 ***
sexfemale           3.9612     1.3405   2.955 0.010442 *  
age_yr             -1.1009     0.1691  -6.511 1.38e-05 ***
as.factor(educa)2   6.7660     2.2988   2.943 0.010686 *  
as.factor(educa)3  14.1302     2.2394   6.310 1.92e-05 ***
as.factor(educa)4  15.4776     1.8657   8.296 8.95e-07 ***
as.factor(educa)5  19.8650     2.0524   9.679 1.40e-07 ***
lg_hag:age_yr       -0.5236     0.2555  -2.049 0.07862 .
```

So in this model, the p value for the interaction is 0.07862, limit to the significance

However, when I run the model without interaction, and then i do a anova (with a Chi square test as the models are GLM) between the two models (with and without interaction), i got a p-value of 0.04 (which is supposed to be the real p value of inteaction, in my view)

```
Working (Rao-Scott) LRT for lg_hag:age_yr
Working 2logLR =  4.199194 p= 0.041893
```

Please if someone could give me an advice on what is the difference between the two p value, and which one to use to attest for the significance of the interaction.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you give some more details about what kind of model you fit and what your predictors are?

Comment: I am fitting GLM models, and my predictors are both continuous (age, exposure (logtransformed), and categorical (sex, race, education) variables. Thank you for your interest